# How to convert a masonry JS script to React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, masonry

Could someone help me to convert the masonry JS script which is linked on the codepen below, for use in a react application ?

[CodePen - CSS Grid Masonry](https://codepen.io/andybarefoot/pen/QMeZda)

```
function resizeGridItem(item){
  grid = document.getElementsByClassName("grid")[0];
  rowHeight = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(grid).getPropertyValue('grid-auto-rows'));
  rowGap = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(grid).getPropertyValue('grid-row-gap'));
  rowSpan = Math.ceil((item.querySelector('.content').getBoundingClientRect().height+rowGap)/(rowHeight+rowGap));
    item.style.gridRowEnd = "span "+rowSpan;
}

function resizeAllGridItems(){
  allItems = document.getElementsByClassName("item");
  for(x=0;x<allItems.length;x++){
    resizeGridItem(allItems[x]);
  }
}

function resizeInstance(instance){
    item = instance.elements[0];
  resizeGridItem(item);
}

window.onload = resizeAllGridItems();
window.addEventListener("resize", resizeAllGridItems);

allItems = document.getElementsByClassName("item");
for(x=0;x<allItems.length;x++){
  imagesLoaded( allItems[x], resizeInstance);
}
```

I'm starting in react application and I would like to have a little help, please...

In advance, thank you, thank you so much.

Best regards

Comment: Can you try to use this library, https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-responsive-masonry ?

Comment: @DatHo, Hi, thank you for your reply. This masonry module doesn't do what i want. I want a masonry which is based on the smallest height of a column, like in the example given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For information, I found the library "react-masonry-component" that do exactly what I want.